# Bundler::GemNotFound and bundler version in traceback is different from the one in gemfile.lock

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I'm getting this error

```
Could not find coderay-1.1.3 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:87:in `block in materialize'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:81:in `map!'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:81:in `materialize'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:170:in `specs'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:237:in `specs_for'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:20:in `setup'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler.rb:109:in `setup'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler.rb:114:in `require'
/opt/project/end-to-end-test/support/env.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/cucumber-3.1.2/lib/cucumber/glue/registry_and_more.rb:107:in `load'
```

while bundler version in Gemfile.lock is

```
BUNDLED WITH
    2.1.4
```

More information about environment:

```
rvm list
 > =* ruby-2.7.0 [ x86_64 ]

which bundler
 > /Users/vakalini/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/bin/bundler

echo $PATH
 > /Users/vakalini/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/bin:/Users/vakalini/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0@global/bin:/Users/vakalini/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/bin:/Users/vakalini/.rvm/bin:/Users/vakalini/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/bin/git:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/chrome_driver

bundler --version
 > Bundler version 2.1.4

bundle config list
 > Settings are listed in order of priority. The top value will be used.
 > default
 > Set for the current user (/Users/vakalini/.bundle/config): "2.1.4"

 > path
 > Set for your local app (/Users/vakalini/<path_to_gemfile>/.bundle/config): "/usr/local/bundle/gems"
```

I tried many times in different order

```
 - bundle install
 - sudo bundle install
 - gem uninstall bundler
 - gem install budler
 - deleted Gemfile.lock
 - updated  ~/.bundle/config with v 2.1.4
 - rm -rf ~/.bundle/ ~/.gem/bundler/ ~/.gems/cache/bundler/
 - rm -rf /Users/vakalini/<path_to_gemfile>/.bundle/
 - rm -rf vendor/cache/
```

What could be the problem and what is this location from traceback `/usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb` - I can't find it on my computer

Comment: Delete the Gem.lock file and then run `bundle install` this could solve the problem.

Comment: thanks, I tried it many times - doesn't help

Comment: Could you show how you get this error, which code you run in order to get it.? It seems you are missing `coderay`. Have you tried `bundle install coderay` after you insert it to your GEMFILE like: `gem 'coderay', 1.1.3`?

Comment: coderay is present 
gem list | grep "coderay" => coderay (1.1.3)
The error fires when I try to run tests (docker-compose run test).

Comment: As I understand it's installed on 2.1.4, but when I try to run tests it looks for coderay in 2.0.2 directory
While 2.0.2 is uninstalled completely, .bundle/ and vendor/cache/ are cleaned

Comment: have you changed something in your Gemfile or Compose file? If yes you need to rebuild. you should run first `docker-compose run web bundle install` and then `docker-compose up --build` (For details https://docs.docker.com/compose/rails/ ). If this does not solve the issue could be related to the way bundler works in Docker [here](https://bundler.io/guides/bundler_docker_guide.html) is described what to do.